# I can't use paste flipped in the animation

Tags: animation

[image]I imported a Mixamo 3D model to make an animation with the model and rigging ready, but when I try to use paste flipped on the legs, the keyframe stays the same as the original.

Here is a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/lABRgLMQWlg

Comment: hello, have you checked the bones name? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure but i think the bones name is right. I uploaded my file here https://pasteall.org/blend/f655de94f41d4b0ea9c91b65fd80d636

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

To *Paste Pose Flipped* you need to have bones that have the same name but with the opposite suffixe, and you need to use *_Left/_Right*, or *_L/_R* or *.L/.R*.

For example *lowerleg_L/lowerleg_R*

It's not the case here, your bones don't have the same name and don't have any suffixes.

Comment: OMG it worked!! Really needed to rename the bones. Thank you my friend